# Capacitor when short circuited

Tags: capacitor, capacitance

What happens to a  charged capacitor when it is short circuited ? Will it going to damage ? Or will it going to be safe ?

Comment: Depends on the cap's type. Might get dangerous with low ESR high-capacity super caps.

Answer (score 4):

You can think of shorting a charged capacitor like you would shorting a battery. When you short a storage device the only resistance in the circuit is the tiny resistance of the wire and the ESR (Equivalent Series Resistance) of the device itself. Assuming a perfect short, the current would be limited only by the ESR which tends to be very low. The high current through a low resistance causes significant heating due to the power dissipated by the ESR, determined by P = I^2*R. This heating degrades the capacitor and can cause long-term damage. You should always discharge a capacitor through an external resistance to limit the current and minimize heating.

Comment: shorting a cap and shorting a lithium battery produce different results.

Comment: @dandavis They both heat up due to high current and low internal resistance. That's all I was trying to say with that analogy. I never said it was a lithium battery.

Comment: right, i was thinking in terms of "will it going to be safe?", there's big diff between batteries (almost any chemistry) and caps not mentioned...

Comment: @dandavis Ah I see. I read it as "is it safe for the capacitor", not "is it safe for the person shorting it"